# Capistrano doesn't create puma.pid file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server, capistrano, pid, puma

I use Capistrano to deploy my Rails app. 
However, when I deploy my application, `puma.pid` file is not being created, which leads to a problem - I can't restart server or deploy new version with capistrano - capistrano fails to stop `puma`, because `puma.pid` don't exests and it assumes no puma processes is running. And I get `ADDRESS ALREADY IN USE` error when capistrano tries to run another version of puma.

Here is my `deploy.rb`

```
lock '3.4.0'

set :application, 'appname'
set :repo_url, 'giturl'
set :deploy_to, '/home/user/appname'
set :pty, false
set :linked_files, %w(config/application.yml config/database.yml)
set :linked_dirs, %w(log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system public/uploads)
set :keep_releases, 5
set :rvm_type, :user
set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.3.0'

set :puma_rackup, -> { File.join(current_path, 'config.ru') }
set :puma_state, "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid, "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_bind, "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/puma.sock" # accept array for multi-bind
set :puma_conf, "#{shared_path}/config/puma.rb"
set :puma_access_log, "#{shared_path}/log/puma_error.log"
set :puma_error_log, "#{shared_path}/log/puma_access.log"
set :puma_role, :app
set :puma_env, fetch(:rack_env, fetch(:rails_env, 'production'))
set :puma_threads, 1
set :puma_workers, 1
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true
set :puma_preload_app, true

set :sidekiq_config, 'config/sidekiq.yml'
set :sidekiq_log, '/dev/null'
set :sidekiq_processes, 1

set :clockwork_file, "clock.rb"

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Recompile all enterprise themes'
  task :recompile_themes, [:command] => 'deploy:set_rails_env' do |task, args|
    on primary(:app) do
      within current_path do
        with :rails_env => fetch(:rails_env) do
          rake 'themes:recompile'
        end
      end
    end
  end

  after :finishing, "deploy:recompile_themes"
end

require 'appsignal/capistrano'
```

And when I try to stop running Puma, for example, I get the following error:

```
...
DEBUG [37113fcf] Running [ -f /home/user/appname/shared/tmp/pids/puma.pid ] as user@server
DEBUG [37113fcf] Command: [ -f /home/user/appname/shared/tmp/pids/puma.pid ]
DEBUG [37113fcf] Finished in 0.273 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
WARN Puma not running
```

And indeed, `/home/user/appname/shared/tmp/pids/puma.pid` file don't exists. Do I need to create it manually or something? sidekiq.pid that is also being created the same way can be found in the same directory, so I don't think it's a permissions issue.

Any advices on how to approach this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume you are using the [capistrano3-puma gem](https://github.com/seuros/capistrano-puma). Here's how that gem works: **The various `puma_*` settings have no effect on Puma directly.** These settings aren't passed from Capistrano to Puma. Puma gets all of its settings from the `config/puma.rb` file. In order for your `puma_*` settings to have any effect, you must explicitly run:

```
cap production puma:config
```

This takes the `puma_*` settings you've specified in Capistrano, builds an appropriate `config.rb` file using those values, and uploads it to the server. Specifically, it places it in `#{shared_path}/config/puma.rb`.

You are supposed to add `config/puma.rb` in your `:linked_files`, so that every deploy gets linked against this shared config.

In other words, the solution is to remove `config/puma.rb` from your source code repository, and instead rely on `cap production puma:config` to generate an appropriate one for you.

Comment: Yes, you were right. It wasn't me who configured the server and apparently that person forgot to execute some initial set up commands

Answer (score 0):

I managed to workaround this by editing `config/puma.rb` file and adding this lines:

```
# Store the pid of the server in the file at "path".
pidfile '/home/user/appname/shared/tmp/pids/puma.pid'

# Use "path" as the file to store the server info state. This is
# used by "pumactl" to query and control the server.
state_path '/home/user/appname/shared/tmp/pids/puma.state'
```

But of course this is far from ideal solution, as it creates duplication, so I am waiting for other, more elegant solutions from the SO community